# Stop call with progressBar Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, progress-bar

Cancelling the `progressBar` call after sharing 100%?
I've tried to do so:

```
public void doJs() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("progress.cancel();");
}
```

Or call the `PF('progress').cancel();`, but without success. 
Follow my `progressBar`.

```
<p:progressBar widgetVar="progress" ajax="true" global="false"
                    value="#{usarLayoutBean.porcentagem}" labelTemplate="{value}%"
                    styleClass="animated">
    <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{usarLayoutBean.doJs()}"/>
</p:progressBar>
```

Comment: So what **does** happen? What if you just display an alert, does that work? Where did you try to call the `PF('progress').cancel();`?

Comment: I'm calling in a 'p: dialog', and OnHide the dialog.

Once it reaches 100%, he keeps calling the getPorcentagem.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for the progress bar. The progress bar stops at 100 and getProgress() is not called again. The onComplete() is called once the Integer progress is equal to 100.

```
<h:form>
        <p:growl id="growl" />
        <p:commandButton value="Start" type="button"
            onclick="PF('pbAjax').start();" />

        <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true"
            value="#{progressBean.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%"
            styleClass="animated" global="false">
            <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{progressBean.onComplete}"
                update="growl" />
        </p:progressBar>
</h:form>
```

Managed Bean

```
package com.test;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProgressBean {
    private Integer progress;

    public Integer getProgress() {
        System.out.println("getProgress() Old - " + progress);

        if (progress == null) {
            progress = 0;
        } else {
            progress = progress + (int) (Math.random() * 35);

            if (progress > 100) // Only when progress = 100 does the onComplete() method gets called.
                progress = 100;
        }

        System.out.println("getProgress() New- " + progress);
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(Integer progress) {
        System.out.println("setProgress()" + progress);
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public void onComplete() {
        System.out.println("onComplete()");

        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Progress Completed"));
        progress = null;
    }

}
```

Output

```
getProgress() Old - null
getProgress() New- 0
getProgress() Old - 0
getProgress() New- 24
getProgress() Old - 24
getProgress() New- 50
getProgress() Old - 50
getProgress() New- 82
getProgress() Old - 82
getProgress() New- 100
onComplete()
```

JSF 2.2.4 , Primefaces 5.3 , Tomcat 8

Comment: Some explanation in text might be in place

Comment: why does the code below work is even better... What are important differences? Why do you assume it was not called in the question? Those are the things that are most important in an answer (learning someone to fish instead of giving fish)

Answer (score -1):

1. The code below won't stop progressBar

   > context.execute("progress.cancel();");

Because the correct way is

```
 context.execute("PF('progress').cancel()");
```

on the doJs() method.

2. Double check if getPorcentagem is returning 100 at least once. If this happens, the progress stops automatically.

Comment: Please re-read the question. OP tried "1". Then 2 is initially just a comment

Comment: DH posted a wrong code which demonstrates the misunderstanding of the use of execute() method and primefaces widgets. 2 is a solution if he manages to solve the problem by returning 100.

Comment: 1: no, in older versions or with the legacy that should work to... no misunderstanding about the execute method there. 2: Solution *IF*... so the checking is a comment

Comment: i know that it worked in older versions. I assumed that he was using the latest. @DH. we expect more details.